# Plotting count in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

My data is like :

```
Portfolio         Type of Assets     Count

Portfolio 1        Type A              10
                   Type B              5
                   Type C              7

Portfolio 2        Type A              5
                   Type B              10
```

I am trying to plot a  Bar graph where the each bar will have Portfolio 1 or similar on x-axis, the count of assets on the bar representing different colors and labels of colors like Red area in a bar represents the Type A assets. How can I plot that, I have tried this for a very long time, but not able to get it. Can anyone throw some hint please?

Answer (score 0):

[Click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqmMnsxAwvI) and watch a YouTude, you will discover select data.